# How to stop horizontal scrolling lines caused by fluorescent light (USA and NTSC)?

Tags: framerate, lighting

I'm trying to record something for a school project and my lighting is underneath fluorescent lighting. My camera is set to 30 fps but records at 29.97 fps (seen on pc). I've tried to copy the clip, move it up and forward by one frame and set the opacity to 50 but it doesn't work. How can I stop the horizontal bars without changing lighting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines exist because the refresh-rate of the light is different and undividable by your framerate. One solution is to set the framerate to the Hertz of your light (which must be known for this case) or to use a light with a refresh-rate that is dividable by your framerate. If none of this is possible, you can still try to deflicker footage using deflicker gizmos for nuke, which work the best from my experience. This should always be your last option though, since the result will not look stunning.

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem is listed in the [AV ARTIFACT ATLAS](https://bavc.github.io/avaa/artifacts/fluorescent_strobing.html) as **FLUORESCENT STROBING**.

This short tutorial shows how to adjust your camera:

[How to AVOID FLICKER and STROBING While Filming](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eTzQky3hRLI) by Blue Mantle Films